# A Hilbert space is separable if and only if it admits a countable orthonormal basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

According to Wikipedia:

> A Hilbert space is separable if and only if it admits a countable orthonormal basis

While this statement seems very reasonable, it is not clear to me how one would go about proving it.

Comment: The Gram-Schmidt procedure.

Comment: Start with a countable dense subset. Use Gram-Schmidt, throwing out dependent elements as you go. Argue that the resulting countable orthonormal subset has a closed span equal to the whole space.